# Controlled form field is not respecting step

Tags: reactjs, forms, semantic-ui-react

Number type controlled form field is not respecting the specified step. It is incrementing the step twice for every click.

I've tried updating to the latest version of semantic-ui-react. I've tried removing the 'control' prop, but it is required.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Form,
  Input,
} from 'semantic-ui-react';

function CreateProduct() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);
  const [product, setProduct] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    price: '',
    media: '',
    description: '',
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value, files } = event.target;
    setProduct(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group widths='equal'>
          <Form.Field
            control={Input}
            name='price'
            label='Price'
            placeholder='Price'
            min='0.00'
            step='0.01'
            type='number'
            value={product.price}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Form.Group> 
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}

export default CreateProduct;
```

I expect the arrows in the number Input component to increment by 0.01.

The actual behavior is that it increments twice for every click.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();    <--  add this line
    const { name, value, files } = event.target;
    setProduct(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
  }
```

Comment: I am not submitting anything in the handleChange function. I am preventingDefault in my handleSubmit function. There is no need to preventDefault until there is a form submission.

Comment: Im sorry but i dont see what you are telling me.